I am getting 404 error while creating dynamic routes in NodeJs / Express.js server
i am creating a dynamic route file for calling all routes declared in routes folder in node js.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>
    <pre>Cannot POST /api/subscribe</pre>
</body>

</html>

For solving this problem i am trying to create this file, But i don't know why this error is occured.
if i use manually declaration for all routes then it's working fine. So please anyone has any idea or suggestion to resolve this stuff from this community?

routes/routes.js

const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const router = express.Router();

// Define the directory where route files are located
const routesDirectory = path.join(__dirname);

// Read all files in the routes directory
fs.readdirSync(routesDirectory).forEach((file) => {
    if (file.endsWith('.js') && file !== 'routes.js') {
        const route = require(path.join(routesDirectory, file));
        const routePath = `/${file.replace('.js', '')}`;
        console.log(`Loading route: ${routePath}`);
        router.use(routePath, route);
    }
});

module.exports = router;

Here is the API code for your review:
subscribeletter: async (req, res) => {
            try {
                const { email } = req.body;
                console.log(" ~ subscribeletter: ~ email:", email)
                if (!email) {
                    return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Email is required.' });
                }
                const templete = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'views', 'subscribeTemplete.html');
                const htmlContentuserset = fs.readFileSync(templete, 'utf8');
                const htmlContent = htmlContentuserset.replace('{{username}}', req.user?.email || email);

                const defaultSubject = `Thanks `;
                await sendEmail(email, defaultSubject, htmlContent);
                res.json({
                    email: email,
                    message: 'Subscribed..'
                });
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error in subscribeletter:', error);
                res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
            }
        }

Also, I am calling it in index file like this :
// Route handling in index.js
app.use('/api', routes);

instead of this if I am using this it works :
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const authRoutes = require('./authRoutes')
const subscribeRoutes = require('./subscribeRoutes')
const productsRoutes = require('./productRoutes')

// fs.readdirSync(__dirname).forEach((file) => {
 
//   if (file !== 'index.js' && file.endsWith('.js')) {
//     const route = require(path.join(__dirname, file));
//     const routeName = `/${file.split('.')[0]}`;
//     router.use(routeName, route);
//     console.log(`Loaded route: ${routeName}`);
//   }
// });

router.use('/auth',authRoutes);
router.use('/subscribe',subscribeRoutes);
router.use('/products',productsRoutes);

module.exports = router;


Are you sure your routes allow for a POST operation not just a GET?

What error message(s) are you seeing? What is the contents of one of your route files?

Hey @JohnRC, Yes I have been permitted to access all methods.

Hy @lucasvw, I am creating one common file in the route folder for calling all routes without calling each for an individual route.

Is /api/subscribe a POST API, please confirm, the problem must be in the method or route.

Yes, @TrushabaB.Jadeja. It's a POST API, and I am sending an email in the body.
And if I comment on this file then it works. So I think the issue is in this file but I am not able to find out where is.

@KevalBadarakhiya please share the API Code in the question, it is not listed right now.

@TrushabaB.Jadeja I have shared it, could you please check it?

You are still not giving us enough context. Please post a minimal, reproducible example. Where are you exporting a router for your code to load?

@lucasvw Could you please review again, I have updated all I have declared in my code.
